# What is it about my question that warrants being downvoted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I know this question in has been asked multiple times, however, they are inherently all unique cases because of the nature of the question itself.

My question:

[Is it possible to use integers as names for arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41370087/is-it-possible-to-use-integers-as-names-for-arrays)

This question has 2 downvotes. I fail to see why anyone would feel the need to downvote it? I'd imagine there must be some kind of logical reason as to why, and that's what I'd like to find out.

My question was clearly asked, I explained why I'm asking the question, I provided an example, and I even gave an example of something that I've already tried. I provided the most amount of information in the shortest possible space, and I made it easy to understand.

I got a very helpful answer that described the exact solution to my problem within minutes. That has 2 upvotes.

Considering this, I'm inclined to believe there must be a logical reason as to why I received the 2 downvotes, and I'd like to know them so I can improve the way I ask my questions down the line.

Comment: The question *looks* kind of stupid until one reads about your (I assume perfectly valid) constraints. Perhaps two people didn't read that far and were annoyed. May be best to ignore it and move on.

Comment: It could help if you updated your question to include the constraints you mention in the comments. Comments have low visibility, and may disappear at any time. Anything of value should be mentioned in the actual post.

Comment: @Yannis
That's a really good point, I'll keep that in mind!

Comment: It strongly reeks of an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), that is, you are attempting to find a workaround for something not present in the language instead of using the language *for* you. It does not help that you say "At the moment, my compiler won't compile unless the array name starts with a character..." because that is Just Because Of C, which you should have known.

Comment: To test Pekka's theory, I've edited the question to move the constraints up to the top and make it harder to miss.

Comment: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/7274/31260)

Comment: Assuming you knew "identifiers cannot begin with numbers", you might have mentioned something like, "I know identifiers cannot begin with numbers but I am looking for a trick to bypass this restriction."

Comment: I don't _see_ any attempt at solving the problem before asking the question. There's no indication of any research into a solution (you may have done it, but you haven't _shown_ any evidence). Since part of the downvote tooltip is "This question does not show any research effort", perhaps that is the reason for at least some of the downvotes.

Comment: I've removed most of your introductory paragraphs, because they don't really add anything.

Comment: @KyleStrand you realize this is not main? on meta this content is totally relevant. You should rollback that edit.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier How so? The first sentence states all that's necessary--specifically, that this is a valid question because each case is unique. I don't think anyone is likely to argue with that, so the rest of the introduction is completely superfluous.

Comment: @KyleStrand I disagree. You seem to uphold this question to the same standard of superfluous as on main. Context doesn't hurt, even if I'll admit it is not completely necessary. Why do you feel compelled to remove it? I mean, almost every question on main has such content.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I really truly do not understand what "context" you think those paragraphs add to the question. They are *only* a defense of *why OP thinks this question should be acceptable on meta*. They add *no* information about what OP is *actually asking*.

Comment: @KyleStrand Who decided such content is not welcome? This is totally not a community consensus. my point is, here, you are not applying a community consensus, as we do on main when removing superfluous content, you are single handedly forcing your view on a meta question.

Comment: @KyleStrand In any event, I don't feel strongly enough on that to really start an edit war, but I hope you'll reconsider that view of yours, if only a bit, as I reconsidered my initial reaction to just roll it back.

Comment: @Félix If OP wants to roll it back, that's fine. I am still of the opinion that if the text adds no value, it should be deleted, regardless of whether it's here or on meta, but if you have a link to a specific answer or other guideline stating otherwise, I'd be interested in reading it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131927/discussion-between-felix-gagnon-grenier-and-kyle-strand).

Comment: What you're actually seeking (I assume) is how to address/resolve the fact that C doesn't allow numeric variables, but instead you asked how to make the complier behave in a fundamentally different way than it is designed to. You should step back and examine other solutions to the previous issue, rather than assuming adjusting the compiler will be the ideal resolution.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

There is one primary reason why people are downvoting this: it seems, on-face, like a stupid question.

One reason it seems stupid is because any competent C programmer knows, or is expected to know, that identifiers cannot begin with numbers. You could know this by checking the standard, or you could know this by a few moments of thought. How is the parser to distinguish between numeric constants if other identifiers can begin with numbers?

Furthermore, it appears from the question itself that you already know this, since you say that you've tried it and the compiler isn't letting you do it. So confusion and frustration begins to set in—what do you expect an answer to contain, when you're asking a question about something that you know is impossible/forbidden by the language specifications?

Also, your question in its original form didn't contain any sort of discussion about why you might want to possibly do something that seems so foolish. There are many reasons why you wouldn't want to use this naming scheme besides technical limitations, not the least of which is that it makes the code extremely difficult to read and understand. Thus, absent a compelling reason, it looks like an exceptionally dumb thing to want to do and therefore not a practical programming problem.

And even once you added in your rationale, you buried it at the bottom, where people were only going to reach it after having read the majority of your question, after they had already drawn whatever conclusions they were going to draw. (And that assumes that people even made it that far before casting a vote.)

Finally, even for people who read and considered your rationale, this still seems like a bad question because it is extremely localized and unlikely to be of help to anyone else in the future. It also still reeks of asking how to do the impossible, when you already know it is impossible, and when you have already figured out the obvious workaround.

(Note that I'm not necessarily endorsing all of these viewpoints, nor defending them as "valid" reasons to downvote a question. I am just describing reality, as I see it. To help stave off *some* of the problems, I've edited your question—but no promises. And it's unlikely that most of the people who cast a downvote will return to remove it, even if my edit were to have changed their impression of the question [which it probably didn't].)

Comment: *And it's unlikely that most of the people who cast a downvote will return to remove it* => especially as they are not notified that an edit happened...

Comment: I must admit, I've read this meta question, all available answers, and the edited version of the question at issue... and I still don't think it's a good question.

Comment: @tiger ...because? Of the reasons I suggested here?

Comment: Pretty much, yeah.

Comment: This is very enlightening, Everything makes a whole lot more sense now. I'll be sure to keep this in mind down the road, thank you for posting :)

Comment: Also, I'd like to mention your edit of my original question is phenomenal. Seeing your edited version versus my original version really helped me understand how I should approach this in the future.
Again, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 27):

"Does not show any research effort" is likely the reason for the downvotes.

The C language specification is tiny compared to most other languages - if you are using the language you at least should read the section on names of variables and list of statements. The post clearly shows that you did not do that nor searched for something similar like [C identifier starts digit](https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%20identifier%20starts%20digit) (Bing link).

Comment: Personally, I beg to differ. I did my research, both by method and by searching online. In the question, I clearly state that you cannot use just integers for the name of an array. That, in and of itself, _technically_ answers the question. Even though the question doesn't state it, what I was looking for was some kind of workaround. Searching online showed me nothing, and neither did trying by myself, so I went to SO for help. I received 2 separate alternatives, which were multidimensional arrays, and prefacing the number with an underscore. Perhaps I need to ask the question itself better?

Comment: @Mr.Potatobadger: Yes I think that's exactly it

Comment: @Mr.Potatobadger "show" is important part of "Does not show any research effort": post does not *demonstrate* that you tried anything (even no standard "searched for weeks (and watched lot of Star Wars)" statement from similarly looking posts). At the moment of downvotes post looked as regular "my homework does not work" post - ridiculous title, obviously wrong code and half-written compiler error. I understand that when *you* read your post it contains a lot of context, but for anyone else it just very low quality and pointless - Cody Gray answer goes into a lot of details.

Comment: @Mr.Potatobadger ...You really should have asked question you are interested in (especially in the title) and state what you are looking for and adding something like "I wanted to use `000` as array names but it is not possible (as sepcified in C language spec), closest thing would be to add prefix but I don't like it because..." There is no way to know what workarounds you are interested in looking at original version - maybe it is standard "I have array of records so each fields is separate array" post...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Very helpful info, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 7):

*This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*

You have all three.

### Research

It is quite simple even without reading a standard to reason how does a compiler know that `i = 001 + 002;` is a mathematical constants or is it a variable.  What you ask is technically impossible to implement in a complier unless you want a compiler that doesn't understand octal numbers.  Yes, you could also consult the standard.  This dovetails with *being useful*. If anyone should easily know an answer, how is a question useful.  That said, there are 100s of questions like this on stack overflow.

### Clarity

Various people have expressed some disbelief as to why you want to do this.  People edited the question to make it more clear.  It was obviously not clear to some people why you need this.

### Useful

Many many professional programmers would cringe to see a variable like `_001` in use.  I understand you are porting code.  However, does the actual original Sega arrays have any purpose?  At least something like `blit_001` is much more concise than just `_001`.  I don't think you have thought about the variables/arrays very much.  They **MUST** have a use or they shouldn't be ported.  Prefixing with some in-cling of the use will disambiguate them and make the code more understandable.

Maybe your are only using this for your own use and never want anyone to see it.  However, if anyone looks at your code or (others like it) the question is *not useful* but also HARMFUL.  I suspect that is the #1 reason for the down votes, although a combination of all will contribute.

You can always use comments near the variable if you are concerned about cross referencing with the original code.

---

You shouldn't let the down votes deter you.  It should be an opportunity to learn something.  Hopefully that has already happened.

Comment: Trust me, the downvotes weren't deterring. After all, I posted this question as an opportunity to learn something!

The arrays are absolutely essential. They are the core definitions of what makes up the level, and without (a very high quantity) of them, the game will not function at all.

Also, I ended up prefacing each number with h. h001, h002, etc. This is because each array belongs to something called a "heightmask" I have another set of arrays made up of the heightmask arrays, and those are labeled c001, c002, etc. C, standing for "chunk", as levels are made of chunks of heightmasks.